# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql, pls-00103

I can't remove error

> ERROR at line 18: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting
>   one of the following:    constant exception 
>       table LONG_ double ref    char time timestamp interval date binary national character    nchar

My procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_schedule( id IN VARCHAR2,ac1st IN ARCHAR2,ac2nd IN VARCHAR2,ac3rd IN VARCHAR2 ,sleeper IN VARCHAR2)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE
   query_str   VARCHAR2(512);
   ac1   VARCHAR2(10);
   ac2   VARCHAR2(10);
   ac3   VARCHAR2(10);
   slp   VARCHAR2(10);
   ac1 := 'ac1st'||id;
   ac2 := 'ac2nd'||id;
   ac3 := 'ac3rd'||id;
   slp := 'sleeper'||id;

  query_str := 'alter table schedule 
  add( :1   number default ( :2) not null  ,
    :3 number default ( :4 ) not null  ,
    :5 number default ( :6) not null  ,
    :7 number default ( :8) not null    )';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str using ac1,ac1st,ac2,ac2nd,ac3,ac3rd,slp,sleeper ;
commit;
END create_schedule ;
/
```

Comment: You can't use bind variables for dynamic DDL statements. But why are you adding columns to a table - surely adding a schedule should create a new row, not modify the table structure? That looks like a really bad data model.

Answer (score 2):

You have some mistakes ( `ARCHAR2` parameter, the position of `BEGIN`, the unneeded `DECLARE`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_schedule( id IN VARCHAR2,ac1st IN VARCHAR2,ac2nd IN VARCHAR2,ac3rd IN VARCHAR2 ,sleeper IN VARCHAR2)
AS 
   query_str   VARCHAR2(512);
   ac1   VARCHAR2(10);
   ac2   VARCHAR2(10);
   ac3   VARCHAR2(10);
   slp   VARCHAR2(10);
begin   
   ac1 := 'ac1st'||id;
   ac2 := 'ac2nd'||id;
   ac3 := 'ac3rd'||id;
   slp := 'sleeper'||id;

  query_str := 'alter table schedule 
  add( :1   number default ( :2) not null  ,
    :3 number default ( :4 ) not null  ,
    :5 number default ( :6) not null  ,
    :7 number default ( :8) not null    )';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str using ac1,ac1st,ac2,ac2nd,ac3,ac3rd,slp,sleeper ;
commit;
END create_schedule ;
/
```

Comment: That fixes the compilation errors, but doesn't really *explain* the exact error they were getting (from the `:=` being in the wrong place and being seen as an invalid part of a declaration, because of the mistakes you pointed out).